# Azure DevOps Build and Release-Pipeline with GitFlow Branching

Tags: git, azure, deployment, azure-devops, continuous-integration

**Given:**

- Azure DevOps
- GitFlow Branching

  - Develop --> Staging
  - Master --> Prod
- Multiple Projects

Based on [this blog](http://thecollaborationcorner.com/2019/02/28/azure-devops-with-spfx-gitflow-gitversion/) I wanted to configure the build and release-pipeline. But it looks like this will not work with multiple artifacts

I have following Pipelines:
[image]

In this example I did some changes to one of the projects (WebSPA) and merged it into master-branch.

But the release will not work because of not met conditions
[image]

AKS Staging want only artifacts of develop and AKS Production only artifacts of master. Only the latest build-artifacts are recognized. In this example there are changes in develop, which shall not be merged to master.
[image]

My hope was to reuse as many things as possible. But from what I see I have to duplicate the artifacts. One for develop and one for master? Are there better possibilities to use GitFlow-branching with Azure Devops?

**What I'm not able to do:**

- use another branching model
- use another CI/CD
- have separate release pipelines for each project/artifact

Comment: fairly certain you need to use a single release per build. not a single release for everything

Comment: Hi, how the thing going? You set multi condition filters but only one triggered, that is why you get the error. About release and build, I agreed with @4c74356b41, a single release per build. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it and it will help other community users who get the same error. If not, you can be free to leave you comment, and I will follow it in time : ).

Answer (score 0):

About your attachment, the Artifact condition not met error. You have set many conditions in the Artifact filters. The Artifac filters meaning is, select artifact condition(s) to trigger a new deployment. A release will be deployed to this stage only if **all** artifact conditions match.

You release pipeline is triggered by one build pipeline artifact, and it can't match all the artifact filters, so you will get the Artifact condition not met error.